# How to merge array on behalf of a key value

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have an array

```
{
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [filterType] => checkbox
            [sfid] => a1d1I000000jrmwQAA
            [name] => Publication Year
            [specValues] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 3
                    [value] => 1953
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [filterType] => checkbox
            [sfid] => a1d1I000000jrmwQAA
            [name] => Publication Year
            [specValues] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [value] => 1954
                )

        )

)



}
```

But I want to merge array if sfid is same i.e i want result

```
{
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [filterType] => checkbox
            [sfid] => a1d1I000000jrmwQAA
            [name] => Publication Year
            [specValues] => Array(
                                  [0]     =>array(
                                                    [count] => 3
                                                    [value] => 1953
                                                )
                                  [1]     =>array(
                                                    [count] => 1
                                                    [value] => 1954
                                                )

                                    )
         )
         )


}
```

Comment: have you done so far? can you provide your code?

Comment: I am still tring to get my desired result but I failed

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, show us your code, and show us what has failed.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to iterate your array and add the row to the output if it is not in there already (you can use sfid as keys) and add specValues to the correct row.

```
<?php

$input = [
  [ 
    'filterType' => 'checkbox',
    'sfid' => 'a1d1I000000jrmwQAA',
    'name' => 'Publication Year',
    'specValues' => [
      'count' => 3,
      'value' => 1953,
    ],
  ],
  [ 
    'filterType' => 'checkbox',
    'sfid' => 'a1d1I000000jrmwQAA',
    'name' => 'Publication Year',
    'specValues' => [
      'count' => 1,
      'value' => 1954,
    ],
  ],
];

$data = [];
foreach ($input as $row) {
  if (!isset($data[$row['sfid']])) {
    $data[$row['sfid']] = [
      'filterType' => $row['filterType'],
      'sfid' => $row['sfid'],
      'name' => $row['name'],
      'specValues' => [],
    ];
  } 
  
  $data[$row['sfid']]['specValues'][] = $row['specValues'];
}

var_dump(array_values($data));
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["filterType"]=>
    string(8) "checkbox"
    ["sfid"]=>
    string(18) "a1d1I000000jrmwQAA"
    ["name"]=>
    string(16) "Publication Year"
    ["specValues"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["count"]=>
        int(3)
        ["value"]=>
        int(1953)
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["count"]=>
        int(1)
        ["value"]=>
        int(1954)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I assume that if sfid is the same, then also filterType and name is the same.